# Python serialize only specific fields to json

Tags: python, json

I have a python class :

```
class Person:

def __init__(self, job_id, name,age , entry_date):
    self.jobId = job_id
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.entry_date = entry_date
```

I have a list of Persons populated with values.
I have some code i use to serialize them :

```
for person in persons_list:
    data = dict(person .__dict__)
    print data
```

This gives me a json with all the fields.

For one operation I need this json with all the fields , for another I only need name and age .

Is there a way I can specify which fields to ignore and reuse the same class without having to recreate ?

Comment: That isn't JSON. But if you were, you can just select the attributes you want, no?

Comment: The output I get is json

Comment: And select the attributes ? thats what im tryign to ask. how do i select the attributes